# App force closes when I try to implement an EditText search in a Listview

Tags: java, android, eclipse, listview, rss

I am new to android. I have created an app which was a pull parser in order to extract items from an Rss feed, into a ListView. Unfortunately my app seems to force close when I try and place code in order implement some sort of filtering mechanism in my ListView. This is the code I have so far, and I have no idea why it seems to crash. Any help would be appreciated.

```
         public class RssFeed extends ListActivity {


// Listview Adapter

ArrayAdapter<string> adapter;
 EditText SearchBox;

List titles;
public static List description;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.rss);

    // Initialising instance variables
    titles = new ArrayList();
    description = new ArrayList();


    try {
        URL url = new URL("http://my.url");

        XmlPullParserFactory factory = XmlPullParserFactory.newInstance();
        factory.setNamespaceAware(false);
        XmlPullParser xpp = factory.newPullParser();
        xpp.setInput(getInputStream(url), "UTF_8");
        boolean insideItem = false;

        /** While the rss feed has not displayed end_document, pull the title and description information */
        int eventType = xpp.getEventType();
        while (eventType != XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT) {
            if (eventType == XmlPullParser.START_TAG) {

                if (xpp.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("item")) {
                    insideItem = true;
                } else if (xpp.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("title")) {
                    if (insideItem)
                        titles.add(xpp.nextText()); 
                } else if (xpp.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("description")) {
                    if (insideItem)
                        description.add(xpp.nextText()); 
                }
            }else if(eventType==XmlPullParser.END_TAG && xpp.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("item")){
                insideItem=false;
            }

            eventType = xpp.next(); 
        }


    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (XmlPullParserException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


    ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, titles);
    setListAdapter(adapter);

    /**
     * Enabling Search Filter
     * */
    SearchBox.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence cs, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {
            // When user changed the Text
            RssFeed.this.adapter.getFilter().filter(cs);   
        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2,
                int arg3) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub                          
        }
    });

}

public InputStream getInputStream(URL url) {
           try {
               return url.openConnection().getInputStream();
           } catch (IOException e) {
               return null;
             }
        }

}
```

And the LogCat:

```
04-12 20:43:00.792: D/dalvikvm(324): GC freed 7597 objects / 316440 bytes in 88ms
04-12 20:43:00.852: D/AndroidRuntime(324): Shutting down VM
04-12 20:43:00.852: W/dalvikvm(324): threadid=3: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001b188)
04-12 20:43:00.852: E/AndroidRuntime(324): Uncaught handler: thread main exiting due to uncaught exception
04-12 20:43:00.862: E/AndroidRuntime(324): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{org.me.myandroidstuff.simpleRssReader/org.me.myandroidstuff.TrafficScotlandPrototype.RssFeed}: java.lang.NullPointerException
04-12 20:43:00.862: E/AndroidRuntime(324):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2496)
04-12 20:43:00.862: E/AndroidRuntime(324):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2512)
04-12 20:43:00.862: E/AndroidRuntime(324):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2200(ActivityThread.java:119)
04-12 20:43:00.862: E/AndroidRuntime(324):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1863)
04-12 20:43:00.862: E/AndroidRuntime(324):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-12 20:43:00.862: E/AndroidRuntime(324):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
04-12 20:43:00.862: E/AndroidRuntime(324):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4363)
04-12 20:43:00.862: E/AndroidRuntime(324):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-12 20:43:00.862: E/AndroidRuntime(324):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
04-12 20:43:00.862: E/AndroidRuntime(324):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:860)
04-12 20:43:00.862: E/AndroidRuntime(324):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
04-12 20:43:00.862: E/AndroidRuntime(324):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-12 20:43:00.862: E/AndroidRuntime(324): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
04-12 20:43:00.862: E/AndroidRuntime(324):  at org.me.myandroidstuff.TrafficScotlandPrototype.RssFeed.onCreate(RssFeed.java:142)
04-12 20:43:00.862: E/AndroidRuntime(324):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
04-12 20:43:00.862: E/AndroidRuntime(324):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2459)
04-12 20:43:00.862: E/AndroidRuntime(324):  ... 11 more
04-12 20:43:00.892: I/dalvikvm(324): threadid=7: reacting to signal 3
04-12 20:43:00.892: E/dalvikvm(324): Unable to open stack trace file '/data/anr/traces.txt': Permission denied
```

Comment: This is the most important statement in your log, check the line number and post the line: Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException 04-12 20:43:00.862: E/AndroidRuntime(324): at org.me.myandroidstuff.TrafficScotlandPrototype.RssFeed.onCreate(RssFeed.java:142)

Comment: Line 142 is   SearchBox.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

Comment: It does, I just took out some stuff that isn't relevant to my problem like a menu etc! Should I put it all in?

Comment: `SearchBox` is `null` because you haven't initialised it.

Answer (score 0):

First of all: the class you posted doesn't have 142 lines, be sure to post the whole class. 
Second: `SearchBox` is null here.

That is because you declared it with

```
EditText SearchBox;
```

but never assigned it which you would usually do from your layout like

```
SearchBox = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.searchBox);
```

(just an example)

`SeachBox` does not have an assigned value at this point so you can't use any methods on it.

Third: Use lower case names like searchBox, it'll make your code easier to read for others and yourself.

Comment: Thanks for helping, I have changed how I declared it to EditText searchBox = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.SearchBox); Unfortunately it still crashes :(

Comment: That's because that line was just an example. You should read up on how to initialize UI components in your code.

Comment: I searched how to initialize an EditText, and then edited the line it gave me?

Comment: So your R.layout.rss does contain an EditText with id SearchBox?

Comment: yeah it does    `<!-- Editext for Search -->
    <EditText android:id="@+id/SearchBox"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="@string/search" />`